# How do I make low quality pictures with Tensorflow for image reconstruction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I want to use an autoencoder to create sharp and high-quality pictures from low quality pictures. For this, I need to create low quality pictures with Tensorflow that are the same size as the original picture.

How do I make a dataset with pictures of reduced quality with Tensorflow? For the sake of reproducibility, let's say I'm starting with this image:

```
from skimage.data import chelsea
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = chelsea()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can resize your image to 1/8th of its original size, and resize it to its original size. This will make the picture blurry/pixelated. Then, pass the original image as the target. For instance:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage.data import chelsea
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

images = tf.stack([chelsea() for i in range(10)])
_, h, w, c = images.shape

reduce_quality = lambda x: tf.image.resize(tf.image.resize(x, (h//8, w//8)), (h, w))

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images).\
    map(lambda x: (tf.cast(reduce_quality(x), tf.int32), x))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
titles = ['Reduced Quality', 'Original']
for index, (image, title) in enumerate(zip(next(iter(ds)), titles)):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, index + 1)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    plt.title(title)
    ax.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]